# Is there a term for the position where two knights support one another?

Tags: terminology, knights, defense

Is there a term for the position where two knights support one another? I thought I might have seen such a term somewhere, but now I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any wide-spread term for that, but if you describe the knights as "mutually supporting" almost everyone will understand what you mean.

Comment: It needs a special term. Let's coin one. How about "two horsemen of the apocalyse"?

Comment: Yes. That totally answers it -- and more. I hadn't seen that. Go ahead and close my question if needed. Thanks! :)

Comment: @RewanDemontay Definitely a duplicate. The main answer there suggests "connected knights" but that doesn't really seem all that common. It doesn't exactly prove anything, but the phrase is lacking in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess#C. It does make a fair amount of sense, though, so it is probably the best candidate.

Comment: Knightshake? Knight + handshake.